# Mongodb Sum query returns nothing

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this example of activities row collection

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ec90b5258a37c002509b27d"), 
  "user_hash" : "asdsc4be9fe7xxx", 
  "type" : "Expense", 
  "name" : "Lorem", 
  "amount" : 10000, 
  "date_created" : 1590233938 
}
```

I'd like to collect the sum amount of the activity with this aggregate code

```
db.activities.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: 
        {
          _id: "$id", 
          total: { $sum: "$amount" } 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
      $match: { type: "Expense", "user_hash": "asdsc4be9fe7xxx" } 
    } 
  ] 
)
```

Expected result : {_id: null, total: xxxxx }

Actual result:

Any solution for this? Thank you in Advance

Comment: You'll have to put the `$match` stage before the `$group` stage. After the `$group` stage. The only fields left are `_id` and `total`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 problems with your query:

1. You making the sum aggregation on each individual document instead doing it on the whole collection because you specify `_id: "$id",` while you need to specify `_id: null`.
2. You're performing the `match` stage in the aggregating **after** the group stage. But you need to perform it **before** because after you group the result will be something like:

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "total": 15
}
```

As you can see this object doesn't have any of the fields that the original objects have therefore `0` results will be matched. The order of stages is important because essentially each stage performs some operation based on the result of the previous stage (there're some exceptions when mongodb automatically [optimizes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) stages but different order in these stages doesn't produce different results).

So the query should be:

```js
db.activities.aggregate(
  [
    { 
      $match: { type: "Expense", "user_hash": "asdsc4be9fe7xxx" } 
    },
    {
      $group: 
        {
          _id: null, 
          total: { $sum: "$amount" } 
        } 
    },
  ] 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @Yos,  It works as intended. I don't know that the order of the operation actually matters.